# For which $m,n>1$ is $D_{mn} \cong D_n \times\Bbb Z/m\Bbb Z?$

Tags: group-theory, group-isomorphism, dihedral-groups, direct-product

For which $m,n>1$ is $D_{mn} \cong D_n \times\Bbb Z/m\Bbb Z$?

I did a similar question before and was trying to follow the same format, but it didn't work because I don't know how to find the number of elements of order $2$ in $D_n \times\Bbb Z/m\Bbb Z$

I was thinking about doing four cases:

Case 1: $m$ and $n$ are both even

Case 2: $m$ is even and $n$ is odd

Case 3: $m$ is odd and $n$ is even (which would be very similar to Case 2)

Case 4: $m$ and $n$ are both odd

Now I am not sure where to go with these cases.

Comment: If $A$ has $r$ elements of *exponent* $2$, and $B$ has $s$ elements of exponent $2$, then $A\times B$ has $rs$ elements of exponent $2$. Since a group has exactly one element of exponent $2$ that is not of *order* $2$...

Comment: Does your version of $D_n$ have $2n$ elements?

Comment: @Shaun: Since $n$ is allowed to be odd, the answer has to be "yes". The only other convention makes $D_k$ have $k$ elements, which necessarily restricts $k$ to be even.

Comment: @Shaun yes $D_n$ has 2n elements, but I figured the number of elements would not work because there will be 2mn elements for both groups, so that won't give me any information on which ones are not isomorphic

Comment: But how many **central** elements of order $2$ do they have?

Comment: @ArturoMagidin would it be mn elements for $D_{mn}$ I'm not sure about the other group

Comment: I'm sorry I am trying really hard to understand the concepts in group theory but it is a very difficult subject for me

Comment: @ArturoMagidin oh wait its 1 for odd dihedral groups and 2 for even dihedral groups correct?

Comment: @ArturoMagidin and for $\Bbb Z/m\Bbb Z$ it is just 1 right? or is it m?

Comment: But you get more in the product; or you can just look at the number of central elements, not just those of order $2$, since every element of the direct factor $\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z}$ is central.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin wait if every element of $\Bbb Z/m\Bbb Z$ is central, wouldn't $D_{mn}$ always have a different number of elements?

Comment: For *most* values of $m$, yes. That will let you reduce the search to a very small number of possible values of $n$ and $m$.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin oh I see so it will be that m=2 and n odd because then $D_{nm}$ will have 2 elements and $D_n \times\Bbb Z/m\Bbb Z$ will be 1$\times$2=2

Comment: Well, and of course $m=1$ (but I see that's excluded). Those are the only *possibilities*. Now you need to determine whether it is actually the case or not.